# Why won't my form requery when I unlink Master and Child Fields using Access Database VBA

Tags: ms-access, parent-child

**What I am Trying to do**
I want to be able to link and unlink master and child fields in Access Database.

**Form Setup**
I have a Master form called "frmQuote" and child subform called PartInformation. Partinformation recordsource is a query.

**Approach**

```
Private Sub Link_Click()
    Me!PartInformation.LinkMasterFields = "PartID"
    Me.PartInformation.LinkChildFields = "PartID"
End Sub


Private Sub Command645_Click()
     Me!PartInformation.LinkMasterFields = ""
     Me.PartInformation.LinkChildFields = ""
     Me.PartInformation.Requery
End Sub
```

**Problem**
I can link and unlink successfully, but the query that is the record source for the Child form "PartInformation" is not requerying or giving me the expected result.  When I unlink the forms my child form is stuck on a new record, instead of showing all the records. Also before I link the Master and Child fields "PartInformation" works as excpected, only after I link and then unlink do I get the issues.

Comment: Does the `PartInformation` query have any`WHERE` clauses or the subform any filtering?

Comment: Yes  Criteria = [Forms]![frmQuote]![frmQuote_CustomerName] is combobox I use to filter the query for partinformation

Comment: Is it possible you are not getting any records on your sub-form because nothing matches `[Forms]![frmQuote]![frmQuote_CustomerName]` or it is null? Unlinking the two forms does not remove this criteria.

Comment: The records are there, before I link the forms I can scroll through record, once I link and then unlink, my form is stuck on a new record, even if I don't change anything

Answer (score 0):

It should work right away - you can/should even skip:

```
Me.PartInformation.Requery
```

as that will happen automatically. Also if you should set the fields back.

So something else is going on.

Comment: what do you mean by setting the fields back? also deleted .requery but am still getting the same results.

Comment: Set them back to the old value: `"PartID"`. It will force a requery at once. If not, study other code or the source query for the subform.

Comment: I cant reset it back until I am able to perform the operations necessary when my form is unlinked, when I unlink the forms I want it to work as it did before I linked them.

Comment: Well, I meant as a test. It has to work. If not, create a new form and subform to confirm the behaviour, then study the current forms for what is different.

Comment: I miss read your comment I'll try to test it and see what happens